# How can I load a databricks table into a databricks notebook using Fugue?

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, fugue

I am testing the Fugue library to compare its benefits compared to purely PySpark, for which I would like to be able to test different operations strictly with Fugue.

Although I could already use Fugue to perform transformations applying Pandas functions, I have not been able to load a databricks table directly with Fugue from a databricks notebook. How could I do it?

Clarifications: I can load the table with PySpark without any problem. Also I have tried following the documentation (https://fugue-tutorials.readthedocs.io/tutorials/beginner/io.html) and tried using:

```
import fugue.api as fa
df = fa.load(f'{db_name_model_data}.{table_name_model_data}', engine=spark)

Output:
NotImplementedError: .my_table_name is not supported
```

I also tried:

```
from fugue import FugueWorkflow, Schema, FugueSQLWorkflow
# Define a Fugue workflow
with FugueWorkflow() as dag:
    # Load a table from a CSV file (example source, replace with your data source)
    df = dag.load(f'{db_name_model_data}.{table_name_model_data}')

    # Show the loaded DataFrame
    df.show()
dag.run()
```

I'm expecting to have any type of DataFrame loaded in "df" by directly using Fugue

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following steps:

**Step 1:** Installing **Fugue**

[image]

**Step 2:** Databricks-connect
In this step, we need to uninstall PySpark to avoid conflicts with Databricks Connect.

```
pip install databricks-connect
```

***Note: to remove pyspark `pip uninstall pyspark`***

After configuring Databricks Connect to connect to the cluster.

```
import pandas as pd
from fugue import transform
from fugue_spark import SparkExecutionEngine
data = pd.DataFrame({'numbers':[1,2,3,4], 'words':['hello','world','apple','banana']})
#schema: *, reversed:str
def reverse_word(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df['reversed'] = df['words'].apply(lambda x: x[::-1])
    return df
spark_df = transform(data, reverse_word, engine=SparkExecutionEngine())
spark_df.show()
```

**Step 3:** Using Fugue-sql on the Cluster

```
from fugue_notebook import setup
setup()
%%fsql spark
SELECT *
  FROM data
TRANSFORM USING reverse_word
 PRINT
```

**Results:**

[image]

**Additional configuration:**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from fugue_spark import SparkExecutionEngine
spark_session = (SparkSession
                 .builder
                 .config("spark.executor.cores",4)
                 .config("fugue.dummy","dummy")
                 .getOrCreate())
engine = SparkExecutionEngine(spark_session, {"additional_conf":"abc"})
```

**Reference:** [Using Fugue on Databricks](https://fugue-tutorials.readthedocs.io/tutorials/applications/use_cases/databricks_connect.html)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I can replicate the code you posted and I the documentation is helpful to understand the principles to use Fugue in databricks.


In my code I can already create transformations on a spark dataframe or Pandas dataframe and even perform operations written in pandas with Spark using Fugue, which works correctly.


However, my question is purely focused on being able to read a databricks table directly from the source (not any other file like csv, yaml, etc. Only databricks tables), without first having to read it as a Pandas dataframe or spark dataframe.

Comment: let me check that for you